# PHP pass through proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I want to create a proxy like application from which I send the header to the server and the response goes right to the client and doesn't use all of the server bandwidth.

The only way I can think of is using PHP cURL for this, but that doesn't work since it downloads the file and the sends it to client. I want to know is there a way to remove or minimize the used bandwidth.

What I want to do:
Clients opens the page, presses the download button, then MY server requests to the file server for the file (using a header) and sends its directly to the client or MY server redirects to client.

Comment: How do you intend to account for the bandwidth used sending to the server and then the server sending it to the client? First law of thermodynamics (abstracted, of course)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with your question. What do you mean by "account"? (It's not like I don't know the word, but I just don't understand it in this context)

Comment: Why not just use a reverse proxy?

Comment: @Memoria "doesn't use server bandwidth." You would obviously HAVE to use bandwidth if you are communicating between a server and client (unless both are localized on the same machine). I guess that's where I was going with the "account for bandwidth".

Comment: Only way I could see that working is with IP Spoofing. But from my knowledge of the TCP protocol the client wouldn't even receive the packets from the server (would work with UDP) and even if you could get IP spoofing to work it would no longer be a proxy. So it's not possible.

Comment: I get that, I meant to not use the full load (download file to the server and then sending it), because I want the client to download the file from the specific server (not a file hosting) using a prefetched cookie and hiding the file origin.

Comment: So  you want the user to download a file from your website without knowing that he is in fact downloading the file from another server (i.e. a "transparent" content-delivery network kind of thing) ?

Comment: **louism** - yes and I need to send a cookie to that server too, so IT gives me the data.

Answer (score 1):

- Clients opens the page presses the download button
- MY server requests to the file server the file and sends to the client 8k at time (in the following example).

This using CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.

```
<?php
/*
 * curl-pass-through-proxy.php
 * 
 * propose: php curl pass through proxy handle: big file, https, autentication
 * example: curl-pass-through-proxy.php?url=precise/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso
 * limitation: don't work on binary if is enabled in php.ini the ;output_handler = ob_gzhandler
 * licence: BSD
 * 
 * Copyright 2014 Gabriel Rota <gabriel.rota@gmail.com>
 * 
 */

  $url = "http://releases.ubuntu.com/" . $_GET["url"]; // NOTE: this example don't use https
  $credentials = "user:pwd";
  $headers = array(
    "GET ".$url." HTTP/1.1",
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($credentials)
  );

  global $filename; // used in fn_CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION setting download filename
  $filename = substr($url, strrpos($url, "/")+1); // find last /

  function fn_CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION($ch, $str){
    $len = strlen($str);
    echo( $str );
    return $len;
  }

  function fn_CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION($ch, $str){ 
    global $filename;
    $len = strlen($str);
    header( $str );
    //~ error_log("curl-pass-through-proxy:fn_CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION:str:".$str.PHP_EOL, 3, "/tmp/curl-pass-through-proxy.log");
    if ( strpos($str, "application/x-iso9660-image") !== false ) {
      header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"" ); // set download filename
    }
    return $len;
  }

  $ch = curl_init(); // init curl resource
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); // a true curl_exec return content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600); // 60 second
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // login $url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // don't check certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // don't check certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // true Return the HTTP headers in string, no good with CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 8192); // 8192 8k
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "fn_CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION"); // handle received headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'fn_CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION'); // callad every CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE

    if ( ! curl_exec($ch) ) {
      error_log( "curl-pass-through-proxy:Error:".curl_error($ch).PHP_EOL, 3, "/tmp/curl-pass-through-proxy.log" );
    }

  curl_close($ch); // close curl resource

?>
```